# Where can one check the definition of the alias of a part of an ansible command?

Tags: bash, ansible, alias

I am working with a set of Ansible playbooks built by a third party.

Recently, I had to recreate the Ansible virtual environment `ansible-venv` (in a development environment called dev1) because a module was incorrectly installed. 
I reinstalled the modules tracked by the requirements.txt file, but some commands no longer work.

Playbooks following this syntax work without issue:

```
/home/myuser/.../ansible-venv/bin/ansible-playbook -f50  playbooks/my_playbook/main.yml
```

However, this command no longer works:

```
ansible my_group -o -b -f50 -m shell -a 'echo "server time: $(date +%H:%M:%S)"' | sort
```

I suspect that the `ansible` word at the beginning of the command is an alias for another command. Which one could it be?

Assuming that my suspicion is correct and I have the same Ansible virtual environment in two development environments, dev1 and dev2, where can I find the definition of the `ansible` keyword in the untouched environment, dev2?

### update

running

```
which ansible
```

in dev2 returns

```
/home/myuser/.../ansible-venv/bin/ansible
```

while on dev1 I get no output.

In dev2, how can I check where the aliasing was defined?

In `/home/myuser/` I have no file `.bashrc` , and in file `.bash_aliases` there is no alias for `ansible`.

Comment: Sounds like a 'local' problem, not something we can solve for you. You can check to where `ansible` leads with command: `which ansible`.

Comment: To list all aliases the command is simply `alias`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @β.εηοιτ.βε

I run in dev2

```
alias grep "ansible"
```

and got in return

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias ansible='/home/my_user/my_path/ansible'
```

the last one is the alias I needed.

I added it to `.bash_aliases` in dev1, then run

```
source .bash_aliases
```

and got the command

```
ansible my_group -o -b -f50 -m shell -a 'echo "server time: $(date +%H:%M:%S)"' | sort
```

working again.